# Why does this compile when I make the class a template?

Tags: c++, templates

I am purposely using the dot and arrow operator incorrectly, but I'm confused why it compiles when I decide to make the class a template.

Compiles:

```
template <class B> 
struct Boss {

  bool operator==( Boss & other ) {

    return this.x == other -> x;

  }

};

int main() {

}
```

Does not compile:

```
struct Boss {

  bool operator==( Boss & other ) {

    return this.x == other -> x;

  }

};

int main() {

}
```

Comment: Which compiler are you trying?

Comment: try to add to your main Boss<int> b1, b2; b1 == b2; This will provoke a compilation error. Code that you don't call is not instantiated.

Comment: @dsign g++ -Wall -pedantic Boss.cpp

Comment: Keep in mind that a template is a **pattern** for creating code. It's only when you **use** the template, by instantiating it, that the code gets created, and it's only then that the actual code is visible to the compiler.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Templates are not fully checked for correctness if they are not instantiated.  They are only checked for syntax. `this.x`, while not semantically correct (because `this` is not, and cannot be a type that supports that operation), is still syntactically correct.

Comment: I added `Boss<int> b;` to main in both examples and it had no effect.

Comment: @KacyRaye: You need to call the actual function.  Member functions of class templates are not instantiated if they are not called.  This is why, for example, you can create a `std::vector` of non-default-constructible types, even though some of vector's member functions and constructors require default-constructibility.

Comment: What do you mean when you say member functions of class templates aren't instantiated until they're called ? Don't the instructions for  functions of class templates just go in the text area like any other function ?

Comment: @KacyRaye: I mean that if you never call `Boss<int>::operator==(Boss<int>)`, then that function is not compiled, and the compiler emits no machine code for that function.  The function does not exist.

Answer (score 1):

It compiles because templates are not checked until you use it. If you try to do something useful in your `main()`, it will give you a compile error.

Comment: They're not _fully_ checked. There are some checks, if only to reliably find the end of the template. E.g. `{` and `}` must be balanced.